# Prawn Rail Error data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I am fairly new to rails so go easy on me. I am trying to get a pdf working via Prawn and I am getting the error:
data must be a two dimensional array of cellable objects

Here is the code

```
class DepositSlip < Prawn::Document

def initialize(payments)
    super()
    @payments = payments
    display_deposit_id  
    line_items                  
end

def display_deposit_id
    text "Deposit Slip Nbr #{@payments.first.deposit_id} goes here "        
end


def line_items
    move_down 20    
    table line_item_rows ##[[1,2],[3,4]]        
end

def line_item_rows

    @payments.each.map do |payment|
    [payment.created_at, payment.payment_amt]

    end                 
end
```

end

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be the date objects. Try to stringify all of your objects for prawn to avoid issues with dates. I believe most number types are alright.

I generally used string interpolation when working with prawn to avoid calling `to_s` on nil.